# decaf::util::NoSuchElementException when trying to connect to Wildfly

Tags: c++, wildfly-8, activemq-cpp

I am getting a decaf::util::NoSuchElementException when ActiveMQ CPP tries to connect to my WildFly instance. I am using the latest ActiveMQ CMS and wildfly 8.0.Final. I am using the example that came with ActiveMQ CPP and pointed to my wildFly instance.

the brokerURI is failover:(tcp://localhost:61613?wireFormat=stomp)

my wildfly standalone-full.xml file is

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:2.0">

    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jacorb"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsf"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jsr77"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.messaging"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.threads"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.batch"/>
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.io"/>
        <extension module="org.wildfly.extension.undertow"/>
    </extensions>


    <management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local"/>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization map-groups-to-roles="false">
                    <properties path="mgmt-groups.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <local default-user="$local" allowed-users="*"/>
                    <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
                <authorization>
                    <properties path="application-roles.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authorization>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <audit-log>
            <formatters>
                <json-formatter name="json-formatter"/>
            </formatters>
            <handlers>
                <file-handler name="file" formatter="json-formatter" path="audit-log.log" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </handlers>
            <logger log-boot="true" log-read-only="false" enabled="false">
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="file"/>
                </handlers>
            </logger>
        </audit-log>
        <management-interfaces>
            <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm" http-upgrade-enabled="true">
                <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
            </http-interface>
        </management-interfaces>
        <access-control provider="simple">
            <role-mapping>
                <role name="SuperUser">
                    <include>
                        <user name="$local"/>
                    </include>
                </role>
            </role-mapping>
        </access-control>
    </management>

    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:2.0">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE" autoflush="true">
                <formatter>
                    <named-formatter name="PATTERN"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.jboss.as.config">
                <level name="DEBUG"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb.config">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
            <formatter name="PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
            <formatter name="COLOR-PATTERN">
                <pattern-formatter pattern="%K{level}%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
            </formatter>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:batch:1.0">
            <job-repository>
                <in-memory/>
            </job-repository>
            <thread-pool>
                <max-threads count="10"/>
                <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
            </thread-pool>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:2.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>

                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:2.0">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:2.0">
            <spec-descriptor-property-replacement>false</spec-descriptor-property-replacement>
            <jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>true</jboss-descriptor-property-replacement>
            <annotation-property-replacement>false</annotation-property-replacement>
            <concurrent>
                <context-services>
                    <context-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" use-transaction-setup-provider="true"/>
                </context-services>
                <managed-thread-factories>
                    <managed-thread-factory name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default" context-service="default"/>
                </managed-thread-factories>
                <managed-executor-services>
                    <managed-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" core-threads="5" max-threads="25" keepalive-time="5000"/>
                </managed-executor-services>
                <managed-scheduled-executor-services>
                    <managed-scheduled-executor-service name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" context-service="default" hung-task-threshold="60000" core-threads="2" keepalive-time="3000"/>
                </managed-scheduled-executor-services>
            </concurrent>
            <default-bindings context-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/context/default" datasource="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" jms-connection-factory="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory" managed-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/executor/default" managed-scheduled-executor-service="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/scheduler/default" managed-thread-factory="java:jboss/ee/concurrency/factory/default"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:2.0">
            <session-bean>
                <stateless>
                    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
                </stateless>
                <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple" passivation-disabled-cache-ref="simple"/>
                <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
            </session-bean>
            <mdb>
                <resource-adapter-ref resource-adapter-name="${ejb.resource-adapter-name:hornetq-ra.rar}"/>
                <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="mdb-strict-max-pool"/>
            </mdb>
            <pools>
                <bean-instance-pools>
                    <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                    <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                </bean-instance-pools>
            </pools>
            <caches>
                <cache name="simple"/>
                <cache name="distributable" passivation-store-ref="infinispan" aliases="passivating clustered"/>
            </caches>
            <passivation-stores>
                <passivation-store name="infinispan" cache-container="ejb" max-size="10000"/>
            </passivation-stores>
            <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <timer-service thread-pool-name="default" default-data-store="default-file-store">
                <data-stores>
                    <file-data-store name="default-file-store" path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
                </data-stores>
            </timer-service>
            <remote connector-ref="http-remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <thread-pools>
                <thread-pool name="default">
                    <max-threads count="10"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
                </thread-pool>
            </thread-pools>
            <iiop enable-by-default="false" use-qualified-name="false"/>
            <default-security-domain value="other"/>
            <default-missing-method-permissions-deny-access value="true"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:io:1.0">
            <worker name="default" io-threads="3"/>
            <buffer-pool name="default" buffer-size="16384" buffers-per-slice="128"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:2.0">
            <cache-container name="web" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.web.infinispan">
                <local-cache name="passivation" batching="true">
                    <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="persistent" batching="true">
                    <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="ejb" default-cache="passivation" module="org.wildfly.clustering.ejb.infinispan" aliases="sfsb">
                <local-cache name="passivation" batching="true">
                    <file-store passivation="true" purge="false"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="persistent" batching="true">
                    <file-store passivation="false" purge="false"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
            <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.hibernate">
                <local-cache name="entity">
                    <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="local-query">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="timestamps">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jacorb:1.3">
            <orb socket-binding="jacorb" ssl-socket-binding="jacorb-ssl">
                <initializers security="identity" transactions="spec"/>
            </orb>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:2.0">
            <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
            <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
            <default-workmanager>
                <short-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </short-running-threads>
                <long-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </long-running-threads>
            </default-workmanager>
            <cached-connection-manager/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
            <expose-resolved-model/>
            <expose-expression-model/>
            <remoting-connector/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.1">
            <jpa default-datasource="" default-extended-persistence-inheritance="DEEP"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsf:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jsr77:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:2.0">
            <mail-session name="default" jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
                <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
            </mail-session>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:messaging:2.0">
            <hornetq-server>
                <persistence-enabled>true</persistence-enabled>
                <security-enabled>false</security-enabled>
                <journal-file-size>102400</journal-file-size>
                <journal-min-files>2</journal-min-files>

                <connectors>
                    <http-connector name="http-connector" socket-binding="http">
                        <param key="http-upgrade-endpoint" value="http-acceptor"/>
                    </http-connector>
                    <http-connector name="http-connector-throughput" socket-binding="http">
                        <param key="http-upgrade-endpoint" value="http-acceptor-throughput"/>
                        <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                    </http-connector>
                    <in-vm-connector name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
                </connectors>

                <acceptors>
                    <http-acceptor http-listener="default" name="http-acceptor"/>
                    <http-acceptor http-listener="default" name="http-acceptor-throughput">
                        <param key="batch-delay" value="50"/>
                        <param key="direct-deliver" value="false"/>
                    </http-acceptor>
                    <in-vm-acceptor name="in-vm" server-id="0"/>
                    <acceptor name="stomp-acceptor">
                        <factory-class>org.hornetq.core.remoting.impl.netty.NettyAcceptorFactory</factory-class>
                        <param key="protocol" value="STOMP"/>
                        <param key="port" value="61613"/>
                        <param key="host" value="0.0.0.0"/>
                    </acceptor>
                </acceptors>

                <security-settings>
                    <security-setting match="#">
                        <permission type="send" roles="guest"/>
                        <permission type="consume" roles="guest"/>
                        <permission type="createNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                        <permission type="deleteNonDurableQueue" roles="guest"/>
                    </security-setting>
                </security-settings>

                <address-settings>
                    <address-setting match="#">
                        <dead-letter-address>jms.queue.DLQ</dead-letter-address>
                        <expiry-address>jms.queue.ExpiryQueue</expiry-address>
                        <redelivery-delay>0</redelivery-delay>
                        <max-size-bytes>10485760</max-size-bytes>
                        <page-size-bytes>2097152</page-size-bytes>
                        <address-full-policy>PAGE</address-full-policy>
                        <message-counter-history-day-limit>10</message-counter-history-day-limit>
                    </address-setting>
                </address-settings>

                <jms-connection-factories>
                    <connection-factory name="InVmConnectionFactory">
                        <connectors>
                            <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                        </connectors>
                        <entries>
                            <entry name="java:/ConnectionFactory"/>
                        </entries>
                    </connection-factory>
                    <connection-factory name="RemoteConnectionFactory">
                        <connectors>
                            <connector-ref connector-name="http-connector"/>
                        </connectors>
                        <entries>
                            <entry name="java:jboss/exported/jms/RemoteConnectionFactory"/>
                        </entries>
                    </connection-factory>
                    <connection-factory name="jmsConnectionFactory">
                        <connectors>
                            <connector-ref connector-name="http-connector"/>
                        </connectors>
                        <entries>
                            <entry name="java:/jmsConnectionFactory"/>
                        </entries>
                        <use-global-pools>true</use-global-pools>
                        <thread-pool-max-size>150</thread-pool-max-size>
                    </connection-factory>
                    <connection-factory name="jms/ConnectionFactory">
                        <connectors>
                            <connector-ref connector-name="http-connector"/>
                        </connectors>
                        <entries>
                            <entry name="java:/jms/ConnectionFactory"/>
                        </entries>
                        <use-global-pools>true</use-global-pools>
                        <thread-pool-max-size>150</thread-pool-max-size>
                    </connection-factory>
                    <pooled-connection-factory name="hornetq-ra">
                        <transaction mode="xa"/>
                        <connectors>
                            <connector-ref connector-name="in-vm"/>
                        </connectors>
                        <entries>
                            <entry name="java:/JmsXA"/>
                            <entry name="java:jboss/DefaultJMSConnectionFactory"/>
                        </entries>
                    </pooled-connection-factory>
                </jms-connection-factories>

                <jms-destinations>

                    <jms-topic name="jms/testTopic">
                        <entry name="java:/jms/testTopic"/>
                    </jms-topic>

                </jms-destinations>
            </hornetq-server>
</subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:2.0">
            <remote-naming/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:2.0">
            <endpoint worker="default"/>
            <http-connector name="http-remoting-connector" connector-ref="default" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:2.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.2">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="RealmDirect" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.1"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:2.0">
            <core-environment>
                <process-id>
                    <uuid/>
                </process-id>
            </core-environment>
            <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
            <coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:undertow:1.0">
            <buffer-caches>
                <buffer-cache name="default" buffer-size="1024" buffers-per-region="1024" max-regions="10"/>
            </buffer-caches>
            <server name="default-server">
                <http-listener name="default" socket-binding="http"/>
                <host name="default-host" alias="localhost">
                    <location name="/" handler="welcome-content"/>
                    <filter-ref name="server-header"/>
                    <filter-ref name="x-powered-by-header"/>
                </host>
            </server>
            <servlet-container name="default" default-buffer-cache="default" stack-trace-on-error="local-only">
                <jsp-config/>
            </servlet-container>
            <handlers>
                <file name="welcome-content" path="${jboss.home.dir}/welcome-content" directory-listing="true"/>
            </handlers>
            <filters>
                <response-header name="server-header" header-name="Server" header-value="Wildfly 8"/>
                <response-header name="x-powered-by-header" header-name="X-Powered-By" header-value="Undertow 1"/>
            </filters>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.2">
            <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
            <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
            <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
            <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
                <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                    <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
                </pre-handler-chain>
            </endpoint-config>
            <client-config name="Standard-Client-Config"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:2.0"/>
    </profile>

    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>

    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9993}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="${jboss.ajp.port:8009}"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="${jboss.http.port:8080}"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="${jboss.https.port:8443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="jacorb" interface="unsecure" port="3528"/>
        <socket-binding name="jacorb-ssl" interface="unsecure" port="3529"/>
        <socket-binding name="messaging-group" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.messaging.group.address:231.7.7.7}" multicast-port="${jboss.messaging.group.port:9876}"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>

</server>
```

UPDATE: It seems the problem happens when the connection is started. ie connection->start()

Comment: You need to provide more details on what your did, URI to connect, Broker configuration etc.

Comment: Is this enough detail?

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue here is that you are trying to use failover with STOMP in CMS which is not supported.  The STOMP support in the CMS lib is mainly for experimentation and not production ready.  If you have to use STOMP then I'd recommend finding a real STOMP client that does what you need.

Comment: i removed the failover and i am still getting the same problem. I have looked around and really dont see a better client the CMS and also see that people have had this working with minor changes to queue/topic names.